# Python: convert output of confidence interval to excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I calculated a 95% confidence interval in Python with this code:

```
d = st.t.interval(alpha=0.95, df=len(df_efw)-1, loc=np.mean(df_efw).mean(), scale=st.sem(df_efw.stack()))
```

My output is: `(2540.3603658087004, 2640.3233923612343)`

I want to convert this into an exisiting excel sheet with this code:

```
ws.cell(row=4, column= 3).value = d
```

But my error is: `ValueError: Cannot convert (2540.3603658087004, 2640.3233923612343) to Excel`

How can i convert it to excel? I would prefer it if i can convert a single data in one cell (2530,36 is in C4 and 2640,32 is in C5).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the row and column notation, access the tuple items individually and increment the row when writing with `ws.cell`.

```py
ws.cell(row=4, column= 3).value = d[0] # C4
ws.cell(row=5, column= 3).value = d[1] # C5
```